# How is the SMM2 stage "Do not... look... left..." implemented?

Tags: super-mario-maker-2

I saw some interesting course in Super Mario Maker 2, for example, the 1st course in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O80KMDPivHA).

I don't understand how it's made, maybe some enemies hiding over the ceiling? How can I use this mechanic?

Comment: the very first death shows what is going on, sort of. when the player looks left a muncher falls down and hits the Switch that toggles off the blocks. A boo likely triggers it, as they have looking mechanics, and they appear throughout the stage. I wont answer because I have never played Mario Maker and dont know its rules.... but thats what it looks like as an onlooker.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like there's a couple designs, but they mostly involve Boo, Bob-omb, and Muncher enemies. Basically, there's a Muncher sitting on top of a "eyes closed" Boo, which makes it solid. As soon as you look in the opposite direction, the Boo activates, becoming intangible and allowing the Muncher to fall down. This will trigger the Bob-omb right next to the Muncher, causing it to explode. The explosion will then in turn activate a nearby P-Switch, which of course causes the level to collapse. So, as a hasty ASCII art diagram:

```
POM     P = P-Switch   O = Bob-omb
XXB     M = Muncher    B = Boo       X = Solid Block
```

This is the simplest version, but there's more advanced versions as well which can capture the Boo and bring it out of the level.

For more info, here is an [informative video tutorial](https://youtu.be/83CjDuDPMQY) on how these types of levels are crafted.

Comment: This is mostly correct, the only thing is, don't do a solid block under the bomb.  The solid block has a chance to shove the muncher off of the boo without triggering the bomb.  Use a donut or some other semi-solid instead.  Also, this design can be improved on, such as adding a boxed in clown car on the other side of the detector to trap the ghost once you are past it.  Finally, you will need multiple detectors throughout a level in order for this to work for the entire level.

Comment: @lI True. The video has more details and explains much better than I can in text.

Comment: Note, it's not that the Boo becomes intangible - it's the fact that it moves, which also moves the Muncher stacked on its back, which crushes the Bomb between the Muncher and whatever (the P switch in this case), and a crushed bomb goes off, which destroys the block above the P Switch, causing the Muncher above that block to fall down and activate the P. (Did you know the "P" in P switch stands for "Block"?)

Comment: For some reason I come back lately, thanks for your answer ^_^